# How can I optimize this linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table `EmployeDetails`. I am deleting rows from this table by first getting a list of the employees. Using remove range function of linq but it's taking too much time I have 10000 records in the table.

```
_dbRepository.Write( ctx => ctx.EmployeDetails.RemoveRange(
         ctx.EmployeDetails.Where(
             v => !v.LastLogin.HasValue || DbFunctions.DiffDays(DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(v.LastUpdate.Value.Year, v.LastUpdate.Value.Month, v.LastUpdate.Value.Day, 0, 0, 0), today) > 0)));
};
```

Comment: You can try executing SQL Delete command directly on the context. Follow this http://encodo.com/en/blogs.php?entry_id=%20311

Comment: Write it in SQL not LINQ or use a SP.  Unpopular I know, but sometimes these old ways still work :)

Comment: How long does it take? How many records are you deleting? What is the table structure? (column + indexes)? I guess you are using EF? and what RDBMS?

Comment: Maybe use a profiler (SQL Profiler if mssql) to inspect the sql that's being generated for this query, then have a look at the execution plan. That will let you know where the bottle neck is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_dbRepository.Write( ctx =>       ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"
delete from EmployeDetails
where LastLogin is null
or CONVERT(date, LastUpdate) > {0}", today));
```